# How do I get Promises to work when using Jest CLI?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, reactjs, jestjs

I'm attempting to test a promise with Jest CLI, this code executes as it should when it's run in the browser. However I want to start writing tests for it.

```
class ListCollection {
  constructor() { 
    this.items = new Array();
  }

  addItem(string) {
    const addItemPromise = new Promise(
      function (resolve, reject) {
        // set up async getting like a XMLHttpRequest
        setTimeout( () => {
          this.items.push(string);
          resolve(string);
        }.bind(this), 2000);
      }.bind(this)
    );
    return addItemPromise;
  }
}
```

Currently I'm trying to get this very basic test to work. I'm testing with `pit` as per the [documentation which links to jasmine-pit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-pit).

```
jest.dontMock('../collections');

import Collection       from '../collections';

describe("Collection", () => {
    let collection;

    beforeEach(() => {
        collection = new Collection();
    });

    describe("Adding an item", () => {
        pit('Spec 1', function () {
            return collection.addItem("Hello World").then(function (string) {
                expect(string).toBe("Hello World");
            });
        });
    });
})
```

When I run my tests with `babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/jest`, the test above fails with this as it's stack trace. Notably I get `Promise is not defined`.

```
Rollos-Mac-Pro:react-boilerplate Rollo$ babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/jest
Using Jest CLI v0.4.0
 FAIL  app/collections/__tests__/collectionTests.js
ReferenceError: /Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/app/collections/__tests__/collectionTests.js: /Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/app/collections/collections.js: **Promise is not defined**
    at ListCollection.addItem (/Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/app/collections/collections.js:24:34)
    at /Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/app/collections/collections.js:48:12
    at Object.runContentWithLocalBindings (/Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/utils.js:361:17)
    at Loader._execModule (/Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:250:9)
    at Loader.requireModule (/Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:916:12)
    at Loader.requireModuleOrMock (/Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:937:17)
    at /Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/app/collections/__tests__/collectionTests.js:7:34
    at Object.runContentWithLocalBindings (/Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/utils.js:361:17)
    at Loader._execModule (/Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:250:9)
    at Loader.requireModule (/Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:916:12)
    at jasmineTestRunner (/Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-cli/src/jasmineTestRunner/jasmineTestRunner.js:242:16)
    at /Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-cli/src/TestRunner.js:371:12
    at _fulfilled (/Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at /Users/Rollo/react-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/FakeTimers.js:325:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
```

I don't know how to fix this. The node version I'm using has to be 0.10.x, otherwise I can't run the Jest-CLI. But node version 0.10.x doesn't have promises. I also don't understand how Jest-CLI works with my ES6 classes and syntax but won't recognize Promises.

Any idea how to get promises to work in my setup?

**EDIT**

I've added the `es6-promise` polyfill to the top of my test file and flagged it not to be mocked. This provides an adequate fix.

```
jest.dontMock('es6-promise');
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
```

Comment: Upgrading Node worked for me. Node version 12.7 resolved this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output mentions `babel-node`, which means that `babel` is running as a require hook, compiling your ES6 to ES5 on the fly. You need to include a shim for native promises, and expose it as `global.Promise`. I'd recommend this one: https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise

Comment: I actually get the same stack trace when just using vanilla node.

So if babel converts ES6 to ES5, why are promises not polyfilled? Thanks for the link, I'm going to drop it into my test file and see if it fixes my problem. Will update :-)

Comment: Babel can be told to provide polyfills for ES6 features like `Promise`. I was under the impression that `babel-node` included that by default, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm also under that impression, however Jest and Jasmine are said to do a lot of strange things are runtime that could mess that up.

Comment: Including the polyfill helped, but the promise object is not returning anything

I included `require('es6-promise').polyfill()` at the beginning of the file, but now the tests just time out. For good measure I also made sure that `jest.dontMock('es6-promise');`

Comment: Edit, your answer is the correct one, I didn't realize this but settimeout is mocked.

Answer (score 0):

replace jest `scriptPreprocessor` with babel-jest should work fine for all es6 comparability issues

https://babeljs.io/docs/using-babel/#jest